# Cucumber Runner doesn't load all feature files using Karate

Tags: java, cucumber, karma-runner, cucumber-java, karate

I'm using Karate for testing REST API, now I'm trying to run feature files in parallel:

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = { "@someTest" })
public class ParallelTest {

@Test
public void testParallel() {
    KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, 
    "target/surefire-reports/cucumber-html-reports");
    Assert.assertTrue(stats.getFailCount() == 0, "scenarios failed");
   }
}
```

The test runs only 3 feature files in parallel and doesn't run all 5 features.
I got this code from CucumberRunner.parallel function:

```
CucumberRunner runner = new CucumberRunner(this.getClass());
List<FeatureFile> featureFiles = runner.getFeatureFiles();
```

Then tried to load my feature files, the list size is 3, that means the function didn't load all features.
Any idea why this is happening?

Note: all feature files under the same package.

Parallel() function code:

```
  public static KarateStats parallel(Class clazz, int threadCount, String reportDir) {
    KarateStats stats = KarateStats.startTimer();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    CucumberRunner runner = new CucumberRunner(clazz);
    List<FeatureFile> featureFiles = runner.getFeatureFiles();
    List<Callable<KarateJunitFormatter>> callables = new ArrayList<>(featureFiles.size());
    int count = featureFiles.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int index = i + 1;
        FeatureFile featureFile = featureFiles.get(i);
        callables.add(() -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            KarateJunitFormatter formatter = getFormatter(reportDir, featureFile);
            logger.info(">>>> feature {} of {} on thread {}: {}", index, count, threadName, featureFile.feature.getPath());
            runner.run(featureFile, formatter);
            logger.info("<<<< feature {} of {} on thread {}: {}", index, count, threadName, featureFile.feature.getPath());
            formatter.done();
            return formatter;
        });
    }
    try {
        List<Future<KarateJunitFormatter>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);
        stats.stopTimer();
        for (Future<KarateJunitFormatter> future : futures) {
            KarateJunitFormatter formatter = future.get();
            stats.addToTestCount(formatter.getTestCount());
            stats.addToFailCount(formatter.getFailCount());
            stats.addToSkipCount(formatter.getSkipCount());
            stats.addToTimeTaken(formatter.getTimeTaken());
            if (formatter.isFail()) {
                stats.addToFailedList(formatter.getFeaturePath());
            }
        }
        stats.printStats(threadCount);
        return stats;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest explanation is that the `tags` in the `@CucumberOptions` is having an effect. Try commenting it out and try again.  Else there is nothing I can make out from the information you have provided.

Comment: Hi Peter, 
Thanks for the amazing tool and for your response.
I deleted and recreated all 5 feature files, that solved my problem!

Comment: @NaelAbdeljawad great :) normally that shouldn't happen, so make sure your maven pom.xml has the tweak mentioned in the doc in case you are keeping feature files in `src/test/java` etc. (p.s. do upvote / mark answer as accepted if it helped)